# Where is my zsh getting its git completion settings?

Tags: git, zsh

My zsh does git completion, but I did not configure this myself. How can I figure out where these settings are coming from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*zsh* comes with its own completion library which includes completions for Git commands. Once you enable *zsh*’s completion, these bundle completions will be available.

You usually enable and configure *zsh* completion by running `compinstall` (i.e. `autoload -U compinstall && compinstall`). It will modify your `.zshrc` to include `autoload -Uz compinit` and `compinit` so that completion is initialized for each instance of *zsh*. `compinit` automatically loads completions from *zsh*’s `fpath` directories (see the [“Autoloaded files” section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files) of the [`zshcompsys` manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html)).

For example, my system has two versions of *zsh* installed:

- `/bin/zsh` gets Git completions from
  `/usr/share/zsh/4.3.9/functions/_git` and
- `/opt/local/bin/zsh` gets Git completions from
  `/opt/local/share/zsh/4.3.12/functions/_git`.

The directories of these `_git` files are in the respective shell’s `fpath` (which also includes `site-functions` directory that is next to the version directory).