# zsh completion for "git log"

Tags: git, zsh

When I type:

```
git log p<tab>
```

In Bash it expands it to `git log production/master` (if there's only one branch at existing `production` remote).

How can I have zsh behave like that?

**EDIT**:

This does not work either:

```
git sub<tab>
```

(it should complete to `git submodule`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems zsh version 4.3.10 had some troubles with that. Upgrading to 4.3.12 solved it!

Comment: I followed your advice and [compiled the latest version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88350/installing-the-most-recent-version-of-the-z-shell). Mine is `zsh 4.3.15-dev-0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)` now. Though, I still cannot autocomplete `git submodule`.

Comment: I've installed a precompiled package from a user's PPA for Ubuntu. Guess it might have git completions in this package as well.

Comment: Chris Johnson describes [how you can configure zsh to add autocompletion](http://superuser.com/questions/320207/where-is-my-zsh-getting-its-git-completion-settings). I applied the default settings which makes autocompletion on `git submodule? working.